# Passing a prop into an action creator in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action, react-props

I am trying to pass the ID number (as a prop) into my action creator function on an `onClick` event. I have used this syntax before when using `setState()` but it doesn't seem to be working here. I am new to redux and am not finding an answer in the docs. I have console.logged to confirm that all the necessary props are being passed appropriately.

When I `console.log(action.payload)` in my reducer function, it returns as `undefined`. If you would like me to post more code, I can.

I am concerned with `addCard`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMarket: () => dispatch(actions.addMarket()),
  addCard: () => dispatch(actions.addCard())
});
```

Component which has the `onClick`

```
const MarketDisplay = (props) => (
  <div className="marketBox">
    <h3>{props.totalMarkets}</h3>
    <h3>Market ID:</h3> <p>Market</p>
    <h3>Location:</h3> <p>Location</p>
    <h3>Cards:</h3> <p>Cards</p>
    <h3>% of total:</h3> <p>% of total</p>
    <button onClick={() => props.addCard(props.id)}>Add Card</button>
  </div>
);
```

action object

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes'

export const addCard = (marketId) => ({
  type: types.ADD_CARD,
  payload: marketId,
}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should forward (or proxy) the id to the action creator

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMarket: () => dispatch(actions.addMarket()),
  addCard: (id) => dispatch(actions.addCard(id)) // <-- pass id to action creator
});
```

UI, now passing `props.id` will work.

```
onClick={() => props.addCard(props.id)}
```

## Fun Fact: [You Might Not Need The mapDispatchToProps Function](https://daveceddia.com/redux-mapdispatchtoprops-object-form/)

The redux `connect` HOC will automagically wrap actions in `mapDispatchToProps` in a call to `dispatch`, so you can write a `mapDispatchToProps` that looks like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addMarket: actions.addMarket,
  addCard: actions.addCard
};
```

And since the function signature of `addCard` already takes an id

```
export const addCard = (marketId) => ({
  type: types.ADD_CARD,
  payload: marketId,
});
```

then your `onClick` code will still work as expected.